# Angular2 Router Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have configured Angular2 Router as below:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { Page2} from './page2';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2 }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Plnkr available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9okaVfVSsRhPxexP9HNw)

On Running the code I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: which version you using ? angular2 rc2 or rc4?

Comment: don't know what plnkr is importing

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a route for the case where the user is at the index page of your app, that route is the path '' and it should look like this: `{ path: '', component: MyComponent }`

If you want your default page to be page2 you must tell your index path to redirect to it like this:

```
{ path: 'page2', component: Page2 },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/page2', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

The order here is important, the most specific route should come first.

Answer (score 2):

You should define default router for `''` like:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: Home }, 
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2 }
];
```

Or by using redirect:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/page2', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2 }
];
```

See also the example from angular2 documentation

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect

Answer (score 0):

to be my understanding , you want to use as app.ts page default page and loaded page2 by click **Page2**?

**Option1:** *quick solve issue*

By solving your current console error you can add to your *app.route.ts*

```
import { App} from './app'; 

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: App, useAsDefault: true }
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2 }
];
```

And Result will be

[image]

But you will see your app.ts html will load two time on load! which is not good way to solve!

**Option2:**

As I use in my project,I recommended you create new home page make as default page .Then call Page2 in app.ts

Here is Plnkr   http://plnkr.co/edit/vzl9lw

Would it meet your requirement!